# Executing Teradata fastload in windows cmd

Tags: command-prompt, teradata, runtime.exec

I am trying to run the teradata database commands in windows command prompt through my Java program. But the below code results in the error "**FDL2412 An invalid parameter was specified -- <**". I tried to execute the same fastload command in my command prompt and it works fine. Kindly give your valuable inputs.

```java
import java.io.*; 

public class doscmd 
{ 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
try 
{ 

String fastload = "fastload < C:/Users/FBNK_SECTOR.fld > C:/Users/FBNK_SECTOR.log";
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c " +fastload); 
p.waitFor(); 
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
String line=reader.readLine(); 
while(line!=null) 
{ 
System.out.println(line); 
line=reader.readLine(); 
} 

} 
catch(IOException e1) {} 
catch(InterruptedException e2) {} 

System.out.println("Done"); 
} 
}
```

Comment: There is a JDBC FastLoad API available that may be more appropriate for streaming a flat file to load into Teradata. (Which is how I am interpreting your Java code to be trying to accomplish.)

Comment: 1) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!